# How can I remove decimals from Percent or Currency

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to find out how to remove decimals in a dimension that is set to display percent. By default, it shows two decimals in percent. For example, zero percent will show as 0.00%. How can I make it show 0% instead of 0.00%? I tried to use a calculated field `XRound [ROUND(X,0)]`, but when I set XRound to show percent instead of number, it still shows 0.00% and I see no way to change that to 0%.

Same thing happens with Currency - Google Data Studio adds two decimals by default and I cannot find out how to remove them. For example, it shows $100.00 - how to make it show $100 (without any decimals)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "Style", there is an option to control the decimal precision of metrics.  You can control the decimal precision of all metrics added to a visual individually.

If you don't want decimals to appear, just change this option to zero.

[image: Style > Decimal precision]

Comment: Does anybody know how to change column type from Dimension to Metrics? Mine are from Google Reporting API and all are Dimensions, so I can't adjust decimals precision.

Comment: @HelenKapatsa You should try to make a new question. However, a field can be a metric if it is numeric. Probably your data is stored as strings. To convert it to a metric, you should fix your source to the proper field type or maybe you can hack it and create a new custom field with the expression `CAST(my_field AS NUMBER)` and them use the new created field as a metric. Obviously, it will only work if the string really is a number.

Comment: ROUND function helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74357344/10533376